# why can't I find libc++.1.dylib on imac?

Tags: python, linux, macos, pytorch, torchtext

I want to use pytorch torchtext but failed. Mac system says:

> library not loaded: @rpath/libc++.1.dylib

I fond a lot of solutions about this problem which told me I needed to copy libc++ file to my virtual environment. But suddenly I find I don't have this file in usr/lib, and beyond that, I don't have a lot of files compared with my original mac.

I installed xcode and llvm but still can't find the file.

which software should I install to make the file libc++.1.dylib exist?

Comment: which version of MacOS do you have?

Comment: macOS big sur version:11.1

Comment: have you tried to install xcode command line tools?

Comment: Instaled xcode from apple app store doesn't mean install xcode command line tools?

Comment: I guess not, when I've installed XCode 12 I had to install the command line tools separately

Comment: thans for your responding